# use tls and elastic in fluentbit

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, fluent-bit

I'm trying to send logs to my elastic pod with FluentBit service on  a different VM.
I configured ingress for elastic.

I configured the FluentBit that way:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host <host_ip>
    Port 443
    #Retry_Limit 1
    URI /elastic
    tls On
    tls.verify Off
```

but I keep getting the following error :

```
[2020/10/25 07:34:09] [debug] [out_es] HTTP Status=413 URI=/_bulk
```

it is  possible to yo use TLS in elastic output? if yes can you suggest what I configured wrong?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP 413 is a code for `Payload Too Large`. Try increasing the `http.max_content_length` in elasticsearch.yml

Also note that you are using `tls.verify Off` which does not make sense longterm. If you have an ingress with a certificate (LetsEncrypt?) it should be OK to set `tls.verify On`. Otherwise all looks correct.